# Can a small glass cylinder with "6.00" marking be a fuse?

Tags: identification, surface-mount, fuses

[image]
My guess is that this part soldered to an SMD board is about 20 years old (it's from the controller of a Mecablitz 50MZ-5 wand flash).  The controller currently is not working but that may be due to the crumbling cable.  This part does not show continuity right now.  This does look like a fuse, the "M" mark would mean "mittelträge" (semi-slow blow), but it's only about 7.5mm of length and marked with "6.00".  And I think 6A would be absurd at this size and functionality, with 6mA being way too small for any kind of fuse.

Here it is in context:
[image]

It's cylindrical and could be sand-filled.  All SMD fuses I find nowadays are sort of rectangular.

So what gives?

Comment: Isn't there a hint of a central electrode? That would mean it's not a fuse.

Comment: I was tempted to say "if not, it is a bottle of beer, because 'small' is in the eye of the beholder", but it really isn't a fuse. Interesting!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica That would still leave open the question whether the 6.00 is the percentage of alcohol or the content in microliters.  Probably the latter since alcoholic content cannot be controlled to that precision, but then I don't know how microbreweries work.

Comment: Sure, anything can be a fuse... once

Comment: @Bear A brand new ceramic oscillator will measure pretty much indistinguishable from a blown fuse without special test equipment.  And intact or not, it will not reliably block the kind of voltage a blown fuse is specified to separate without arcing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Specifically, this is muRata CSAC6.00MGC-TC, a 6 MHz SMD cylindrical ceramic resonator. Here is the datasheet for it showing it's dimensional drawings: [MURATA type CSAC/CSACV](https://www.spelektroniikka.fi/kuvat/csac%20resonator.pdf).

[image: muRata CSAC]

Although very similar to a fuse visually, it should not be confused with one. You can verify this with a simple continuity tester: its ends should be connected to pins 52 (XTIN) and 53 (XTOUT) of the TMP47C847F microcontroller shown in your second photo.

[image: TMP47C847F crystal connection]

The part is now obsolete, and this style of crystal resonator packaging is not used by manufacturers nowadays, so it's very unlikely to see a similar resonator mounted on a modern PCB. However, if it somehow breaks (ceramics can be brittle), it's still possible to get old stock replacement from electronic component distributors if you care about authenticity or just replace it with a modern crystal resonator of the same frequency and similar size.

Another Source, sorry for the low resolution:

[image: Murata_CSAC_obsolete]

Comment: +1 Note also that the CM is a Murata logo. See [pdf page 3](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2644211.pdf?_ga=2.162758264.559360493.1690966635-1560709853.1690966635&_gac=1.159459151.1690966635.CjwKCAjw_aemBhBLEiwAT98FMlUrk7XRItebe6JIFsBjtsaa8kQIpvEh0OEdu9fl1Ck21FpCrtRTJBoCczIQAvD_BwE)

Comment: +1 I couldn't find any info on these. Good job.

Comment: I learned something :-). Very nice answer.

Answer (score 15):

That's not a fuse, it's a 6.00 MHz ceramic resonator. See if you can trace the circuit, it should be connected to a micro and maybe some small capacitors.

Comment: There's definitely a microcontroller in the immediate vicinity.  That makes a lot more sense than a fuse, it's just that it looked so much like one.  Thanks!

Comment: @user107063 I've got a circuit board sitting right here with the 4 MHz version, so I recognized it right away.

Comment: A fuse should not be placed so close to the microcontroller but a resonator should be so close.

Comment: I have now "accepted" a different, exhaustive answer because it makes sense to appear at the top of the answer list.  The mouseover for the checkmark says "Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution" which would really apply to your answer perfectly well.  Rest assured I'll keep my +1 at least.

Comment: @user107063 That's okay. I thought they were Murata and tried to find some information on the exact part but didn't have any luck.